# Python dataframe Convert columns to row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do you convert the below dataframe to:

```
State Feature       2020Q1  2020Q2 2020Q3   2020Q4.....2030Q4
AL    Population     100000 100020  100030  100040     100050
AL    InterestRate   1.5    1.5     1.5      1.6        1.6
AZ    Population     200001  200002 200003   200004..... 300002
AZ    InterestRate   2.0    2.0      2.0     2.0 ..........3.0
```

Need output like:

```
State YearQuarter  Population     InterestRate   
AL     2020Q1      100000          1.5
AL     2020Q2      100020          1.5
AL     2020Q3      100030          1.5
AL     2020Q4      100040          1.6
.
.
AL     2030Q3      100050          1.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pivot` and some axis operations:

```
out = (df.pivot(index='State', columns='Feature')
         .rename_axis(columns=['YearQuarter', None])
         .stack('YearQuarter').reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
  State YearQuarter  InterestRate  Population
0    AL      2020Q1           1.5    100000.0
1    AL      2020Q2           1.5    100020.0
2    AL      2020Q3           1.5    100030.0
3    AL      2020Q4           1.6    100040.0
4    AL      2030Q4           1.6    100050.0
5    AZ      2020Q1           2.0    200001.0
6    AZ      2020Q2           2.0    200002.0
7    AZ      2020Q3           2.0    200003.0
8    AZ      2020Q4           2.0    200004.0
9    AZ      2030Q4           3.0    300002.0
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
df.melt(
    ['State','Feature'], var_name='Quarters'
).pivot_table(
    index=['State','Quarters'], 
    columns='Feature', 
    values='value' ).reset_index()
```

```
Feature     State   Quarters    InterestRate    Population
0            AL     2020Q1              1.5     100000.0
1            AL     2020Q2              1.5     100020.0
2            AL     2020Q3              1.5     100030.0
3            AL     2020Q4              1.6     100040.0
4            AL     2030Q4              1.6     100050.0
5            AZ     2020Q1              2.0     200001.0
6            AZ     2020Q2              2.0     200002.0
7            AZ     2020Q3              2.0     200003.0
8            AZ     2020Q4              2.0     200004.0
9            AZ     2030Q4              3.0     300002.0
```